# Git command to include a file from child directory using relative path

Tags: git

I have a Java project "A" which is a directory. I have added all the ".java" files into "git" repository by using the command `git add *.java`. It has included the files from the nested directories inside the "A" directory. Then i have to add some resources to the git repository. The problem here is the resources are available as a sub folder of a sub folder.  Something like "A\B\C\resources.xml". Here the folder name B and C might be anything.
**How can i add a file according to the depth of the file structure?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Git is Linux based windows like path makes the trouble here.
We can use `git add .\\*\\*.xml`. Here backslash is a escape character to escape the other backslash. We can also use just a single forward slash to denote the directory by using `git add ./*/*.xml`.

Comment: Tnks! This works!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you only allowing *.java files? Isn't it much more convenient to add a relevant .gitignore file to your project?

You can consult the following page for a comprehensive list of .gitignore files:
https://github.com/github/gitignore

Most of the popular projects are in there, but you can ofcourse alter a .gitignore file to your own likings. Be sure to pick one that resembles your project the most.

Then it is just a quick `git add .` and all files that should be added are added, no matter in which directory they are.

Answer (score 1):

For your example, if you use command line for git, write next:

```
find . -type f -name '*.xml' | xargs git add
```

where **find** command will find all files, specified by template. 
And you add all your files with xml extension into your repo.
A moment that you have to be at main folder of your java project.

But, also you can use `.gitgnore` file, and within the last one, write

```
git add .
```

And all your files will be added to git repository.